# Nginx url rewrite directory as parameter

Tags: nginx

I want to write an URL such as mysite.com/l360/profile/55 and have NGINX load mysite.com/l360/home.php?path=profile/55 instead.

Unfortunately, I can't just switch to apache2 this time around. So I gotta find a way to make NGINX work.

my problem right now is that mysite.com/l360 loads home.php and mysite.com/l360/home.php work correctly. When I try to do mysite.com/l360/profile it tries to download a BIN file from the server.

Here is my config for that part:

```
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php?$query_string;
            client_max_body_size 50M;
            client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    }

location /l360 {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @l360rw;
}
location @l360rw {
    return 302 /home.php?path=$uri;
}

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index home.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
            include fastcgi_params;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a working solution that only asked I changed my code a bit. The following will give the paramater as path=l360/test/ so all that was needed was a method to strip the home directory of the file from the path name:

```
    location /l360 {
            index home.php;
            try_files /$uri /$uri/ /l360/home.php?path=$uri;
    }

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php?$query_string;
            client_max_body_size 50M;
            client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index home.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
            include fastcgi_params;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try a regular expression with a capture group and the [rewrite statement](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite). Something like this

```
location ^/l360/profile/([0-9]+)$ {
  rewrite /l360/home.php?path=profile/$1
}

location ~ \.php$ {
  try_files $uri =404;
  // I removed the next line mostly because my config doesn't have it
  // REMOVED fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_index home.php;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
  fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
  include fastcgi_params;
}
```

I haven't tested this, and I would be surprised if its work as written. It should give you some clues about one way to do this though.

There are no doubt other ways to do this, others may give better answers, or may help refine my answer to the point it works properly.